# Python Callback from SWIG PyObject_Call Segfault

Tags: c++, python, wxpython, swig, python-c-api

I have a wx.py.Shell.shell widget which lets the user execute python code that interacts with my program. I want to be able to pass a function that the user defines in this space to my C++ code (Through the wxswig generated wrapper around my custom widget)and execute it.

In my C++ code I'm using a std::function <> class to invoke bound functions (C++ or Python)

So I created a simple class to wrap the PyObject with the function call operator. However I get a segfault when I try to call the PyObject *.

```
class PyMenuCallback
{
    PyObject *Func;
public:
    PyMenuCallback(const PyMenuCallback &op2);
    PyMenuCallback(PyObject *func);
    ~PyMenuCallback ();

    void operator() (int id);
};
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
PyMenuCallback::PyMenuCallback(PyObject *func)
    : Func(func)
{
    Py_XINCREF (Func);
    if(!PyCallable_Check(Func))
        cout << "Not a Callable Callback." << endl; //Throw an exception or something
}

PyMenuCallback::PyMenuCallback(const PyMenuCallback &op2)
    : Func (op2.Func)
{
    Py_XINCREF (Func);
    if(!PyCallable_Check(Func))
        cout << "Not a Callable Callback." << endl;
}

PyMenuCallback::~PyMenuCallback()
{
    Py_XDECREF (Func);
}

void PyMenuCallback::operator() (int id)
{
    cout << "Calling Callback" << endl;
    if (Func == 0 || Func == Py_None || !PyCallable_Check(Func))
        return;
    cout << "Building Args" << endl;   
    PyObject *arglist = Py_BuildValue ("(i)",id);
    cout << "Func: " << Func->ob_type->tp_name << " " << Func->ob_refcnt << endl;
    PyObject *result = PyObject_Call(Func,arglist,0); //<<<<<---SEGFAULTS HERE
    cout << "Executed" << endl;
    Py_DECREF(arglist);
    Py_XDECREF(result);
}
```

In my attempts to find what was going on, I put a bunch of print statements. 
One of which prints the type name and reference count the line before the segfault. This results in "function 3" so I have to assume the function has not been destroyed yet.

I'm passing the following to swig:

```
void AddOption (std::string name, PyObject *pycallback);
```

In which I construct a PyMenuCallback

I'm at a loss for what's causing the segfault, any ideas?

Comment: I think you've violated the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) by not supplying an `operator=` for `PyMenuCallback`. I'm not sure if that's the problem here or not though, but it certainly has the potential to cause problems.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this on my machine with a test case. I managed to confirm that `operator=` isn't being used by accident, but the code worked and didn't generate any warnings from valgrind either. Can you expand and simplify your test case a bit perhaps by using `%inline` and `%{%}` to make it so you just have a single interface file? E.g. I used: [this](http://pastebin.com/XYXj3a4p) to test which may have subtle differences to what you're using/wrapping.

Comment: Indeed, good catch, I forgot operator=. It however is not used at the moment, but I shall add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the C++ calling the python callback is within a wxWidget, and the swig wrapper is generated by the special wxPython swig (wxswig?) There is some thread protection required around the function call...

The fixed operator should look like this

```
void PyMenuCallback::operator() (int id)
{
    cout << "Calling Callback" << endl;
    if (Func == 0 || Func == Py_None || !PyCallable_Check(Func))
        return;
    cout << "Building Args" << endl;   
    PyObject *arglist = Py_BuildValue ("(i)",id);
    cout << "Built: " << arglist << endl;
    cout << "Func: " << Func->ob_type->tp_name << " " << Func->ob_refcnt << endl;

    wxPyBlock_t blocked = wxPyBeginBlockThreads(); //Anti-WxSwig 

    PyObject *result = PyObject_Call(Func,arglist,0);

    wxPyEndBlockThreads(blocked);


    cout << "Executed" << endl;
    Py_XDECREF(arglist);
    Py_XDECREF(result);
}
```

Make sure to include

```
#include "wx/wxPython/wxPython.h"
#include "wx/wxPython/wxPython_int.h"
```