# c++ back end call the python level defined callbacks with swig wrapper

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am wrapping a library which was written in C++ to Python API
[libwebqq](https://github.com/gtkqq/libwebqq.git)

There is a type which is defined in boost function .

```
typedef boost::function<void (std::string)> EventListener;
```

Python level can define "EventListener" variable callbacks.

There is also a map structure in C++ level which is event_map in class Adapter.
The key type of event_map is a QQEvent enum type and the value type of event_map is class "Action" which wraps EvenListener.

```
class Action
{

    EventListener _callback;

    public:
    Action (){
        n_actions++;
    }

    Action(const EventListener & cb ){
    setCallback(cb);
    }

    virtual void operator()(std::string data) {
    _callback(data);
    }
    void setCallback(const EventListener & cb){
        _callback = cb;
    }

    virtual ~Action(){ std::cout<<"Destruct Action"<<std::endl; n_actions --; }
    static int n_actions;
};


class Adapter{

    std::map<QQEvent, Action > event_map;

public:
    Adapter();
    ~Adapter();
    void trigger( const QQEvent &event, const std::string data);
    void register_event_handler(QQEvent event, EventListener callback);
    bool is_event_registered(const QQEvent & event);
    void delete_event_handler(QQEvent event);
};
```

"register_event_handler" in class Adapter is the API to register a callback function to related event. 
And C++ back end will call it if event happened. But we need to implement the callbacks in python level. And I wrapped the callback type in "callback.i"

The problem is , when I call the register_event in test python [script](https://github.com/gtkqq/libwebqq/blob/master/wrappers/python/testwrapper.py#L40), a type error always occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testwrapper.py", line 44, in <module>
worker = Worker()
File "testwrapper.py", line 28, in __init__
a.setCallback(self.on_message)
File "/home/devil/linux/libwebqq/wrappers/python/libwebqqpython.py", line 95, in setCallback
def setCallback(self, *args): return _libwebqqpython.Action_setCallback(self, *args)
TypeError: in method 'Action_setCallback', argument 2 of type 'EventListener const &'
Destruct Action
```

Please help to figure out the root cause of this type error and a solution to this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392703/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-call-a-python-function-from-c-with-a-swig-wrapped

Answer (score 14):

The problem seems to be that you haven't included any code to map from a Python callable to your `EventListener` class. It's not provided for free, although it's something that comes up fairly regularly, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435760/python-callback-from-swig-pyobject-call-segfault) which acted as a reference for part of this answer.

Your question has quite a lot of code that's not really relevant to the problem and not quite complete either so I've produced a minimal header file to demonstrate the problem and solution with:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef boost::function<void (std::string)> EventListener;

enum QQEvent { THING };

inline std::map<QQEvent, EventListener>& table() {
  static std::map<QQEvent, EventListener> map;
  return map;
}

inline const EventListener& register_handler(const QQEvent& e, const EventListener& l) {
  return table()[e] = l;
}

inline void test(const QQEvent& e)  {
  table()[e]("Testing");
}
```

Given that header file a simple wrapper would be:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh"
%}

%include "test.hh"
```

I also put together a bit of Python to run this with:

```
import test

def f(x):
  print(x)

test.register_handler(test.THING, f)
test.test(test.THING)
```

With this I can reproduce the error you see:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python3.1 run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 6, in 
    test.register_handler(test.THING, f)
TypeError: in method 'register_handler', argument 2 of type 'EventListener const &'
```

Hopefully we're on the same page now. There's a single version of `register_handler` that expects an object of type `EventListener` (SWIG's generated proxy for the type to be precise). We're not trying to pass an `EventListener` in when we call that function though - it's a Python Callable instead, with not much known on the C++ side - certainly not a type match or implicitly convertible. So we need to add some glue in our interface to mush the Python type into the real C++ type.

We do that by defining an entirely new type, which only exists internally to the SWIG wrapper code (i.e. within `%{ }%`). The type `PyCallback` has one purpose: hold a reference to the real Python thing we're working with and make it look/feel like a function in C++.

Once we've added that `PyCallback` implementation detail (which nobody gets to see) we then need to add another overload for `register_handler`, which takes a `PyObject*` directly and constructs the `PyCallback`+`EventListener` for us. Since this only exists for the purpose of wrapping we use `%inline` to declare, define and wrap all within the SWIG interface file. So our interface file now looks like:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh"

class PyCallback
{
    PyObject *func;
    PyCallback& operator=(const PyCallback&); // Not allowed
public:
    PyCallback(const PyCallback& o) : func(o.func) {
      Py_XINCREF(func);
    }
    PyCallback(PyObject *func) : func(func) {
      Py_XINCREF(this->func);
      assert(PyCallable_Check(this->func));
    }
    ~PyCallback() {
      Py_XDECREF(func);
    }
    void operator()(const std::string& s) {
      if (!func || Py_None == func || !PyCallable_Check(func))
        return;
      PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(s)", s.c_str());
      PyObject *result = PyObject_Call(func,args,0);
      Py_DECREF(args);
      Py_XDECREF(result);
    }
};
%}

%include "test.hh"

%inline %{
  void register_handler(const QQEvent& e, PyObject *callback) {
    register_handler(e, PyCallback(callback));
  }
%}
```

At this point we now have enough for the original test Python to run successfully.

It's worth noting that we could have chosen to hide the original overload of `register_handler`, but in this instance I prefer not to - it's more of a feature than a mistake to leave that visible because it permits you to manipulate C++ defined callbacks also, e.g. you could get/set them from the Python side and expose some core ones as global variables.

In your actual code you'll want to do:

```
%extend Action {
  void setCallback(PyObject *callback) {
    $self->setCallback(PyCallback(callback));
  }
}
```

to overload `Action::setCallback`, after the line `%include "test.hh"`, instead of the `%inline` I used in my example to overload the free function.

Finally you might want to expose `operator()` of your `Action` class using `%rename`, or you could chose to expose the `callback_` member using the [function pointer/member function trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586452/168175).

Comment: Fist of all , thanks for your kindly support. I added the Pycallback class and "extend Action -> setCallback" in file "libwebqq.i", and also changed "inline register_event_handler" to " extend Adapter" because the "register_event_handler" is a method of Adapter. The project can build successfully. But when the C++ level call the python defined callabcks , a segment fault will happen. The error message is "swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'EventListener *', no destructor found."

Comment: @user1530527 - that sounds like several problems. Firstly you need to make sure that when SWIG wraps a type it has a definition of the class sufficient to be able to legally call `delete`. Secondly you might have locking issues if your code is multi-threaded.