# Handling std::function with SWIG

Tags: c++, c++11, swig

Apparently, SWIG does not understand `std::function` and breaks Python bindings. For instance, this works in C++:

```
// Somewhere in the API
typedef std::function<void(const UnitError & error)> UnitErrorHandler;

// Somewhere else in the API
void Unit::setErrorHandler(const UnitErrorHandler & handler) {}

// In the application code
unit->setErrorHandler([](const UnitError & error){
    std::cerr << error << std::endl;
    std::exit(1);
});
```

But this will break code (apart from having a different behaviour for the sake of simplicity, but that's not the point):

```
unit.setErrorHandler(lambda error: len(error))
```

The situation is the same with `def` (ordinary) unbound functions.
So, does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Not sure if it's an option, but this would be "relatively" easy to do using Boost Python.

Comment: See my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11522655/168175 which actually used `std::function` as an example.

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` is relatively new (C++11) so SWIG doesn't have any out-of-the-box solution for it.  While not as flexible, you *can* use function pointers, with a caveat.  Quoting [*5.4.9 Pointers to functions and callbacks*](http://swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn30) in the [docs](http://swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html):

> ...SWIG provides full support for function pointers provided that the callback functions are defined in C and not in the target language.

So passing a lambda will not work.  Read the documentation link for some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

In two lines: create an interface function that takes a command as a string and sets up a functor that is then assigned to the `std::function`. The `operator()` takes care of evaluating the string in the target language.

---

Let's assume that in the header file `mymodule.hh` you have a class `MyModule` with a method `void MyModule::Func(const std::function<double(Bunch&)> & func)` where `Bunch` is another object.

This can be solved defining an interface function that takes a `const char *` representing an expression to eval and wraps it into a functor that will be then assigned to the `std::function`. The good news is that this can entirely done in the swig interface file, without touching the C++ code, here is how (I used tcl, you just have to adapt the `operator()`):

```
%module mymodule
%{
  #include "bunch.hh"
  #include "mymodule.hh"

  extern Tcl_Interp* tcl_interp;

  struct Tcl_bunch_callback {
    std::string callback;
    double operator()(Bunch & bunch)
    {
      Tcl_Obj * bunch_obj = SWIG_Tcl_NewInstanceObj(tcl_interp, &bunch, SWIGTYPE_p_Bunch, /*own pointer?*/0);
      Tcl_SetVar2Ex(tcl_interp, "bunch", (const char*)nullptr, bunch_obj, 0);
      double resultValue;
      const int resultCode = Tcl_ExprDouble(tcl_interp, callback.c_str(), &resultValue);
      if (resultCode != TCL_OK) {
        std::cerr << "WARNING evaluation of tcl expression failed: " 
                  << Tcl_GetStringResult(tcl_interp) << std::endl;
        resultValue = max_double;
      }
      Tcl_DeleteCommand(tcl_interp, Tcl_GetString(bunch_obj)); //remove the used command to avoid leaks
      return resultValue;
    }
  };
%}

%include "bunch.hh"
%include "mymodule.hh"
%extend MyModule
{
  void Func(const char * cmd) {
    $self->Func(std::function<double(Bunch&)>(Tcl_bunch_callback(cmd)));
  }
}
```

In my case the `operator()` is pretty bounded to Tcl, but I'm sure that similar procedures can be written also for the others target languages. Follows some details of it.

I give the user the capability to access the methods of the current `Bunch` being processed in C++ directly from Tcl. The function: `SWIG_NewInstanceObj` allows to convert the `Bunch` pointer in its representation in the target language and creates an instance of it in the interpreter (this function is not documented, but digging a bit in whatever swig-generated wrap file it is not too hard to understand its mechanism). With the following command I set that object to a variable named `bunch` so that it becomes available to the user simply with `$bunch` and all the methods exported with swig are then accessible.

I think it's amazing how such powerful things are made available with such few lines of code thanks to swig!