# How to wrap a c++ function which takes in a function pointer in python using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

Here is a simplified example of what I want to do. Suppose I have the following c++ code in test.h

```
double f(double x);
double myfun(double (*f)(double x));
```

It doesn't really matter for now what these functions do. The important thing is that myfun takes in a function pointer.

After including the test.h file in my interface file, I compiled a python module "test" using SWIG. Now, in Python, I run the following commands:

```
import test
f = test.f
```

This creates a properly working function f, which takes in a double. However, when I try to pass "f" into myfun within python this is what happens:

```
myfun(f)
TypeError: in method 'myfun', argument 1 of type 'double (*)(double)'
```

How do I fix this? I figure I need a typemap declaration in my SWIG interface file, but I am not sure what the proper syntax is or where to put it. I tried

```
%typemap double f(double);
```

but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show your .i too? And what do you mean by "a properly working function f"? is this a Python function? or a C function pointer that you have exported to Python via SWIG?

Answer (score 21):

Note: this answer has a long section on workarounds. If you simply want to use this skip straight to solution 5.

### The problem

You've run into the fact that in Python everything is an object. Before we look at fixing things, first let's understand what's going on as is. I've created a complete example to work with, with a header file:

```
double f(double x) {
  return x*x;
}

double myfun(double (*f)(double x)) {
  fprintf(stdout, "%g\n", f(2.0));
  return -1.0;
}

typedef double (*fptr_t)(double);
fptr_t make_fptr() {
  return f;
}
```

The main changes I've made so far are adding a definition to your declarations so I can test them and a `make_fptr()` function that returns something to Python we know is going to be wrapped as a function pointer.

With this the first SWIG module might look like:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

And we can compile it with:

```
swig2.0 -Wall -python test.i && gcc -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/python2.6 -std=gnu99 -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.c
```

So now we can run this and ask Python about the types we have - the type of `test.f` and the type of the result of calling `test.make_fptr())`:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> type(test.f)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> repr(test.f)
'<built-in function f>'
>>> type(test.make_fptr())
<type 'SwigPyObject'>
>>> repr(test.make_fptr())
"<Swig Object of type 'fptr_t' at 0xf7428530>"
```

So the problem as it stands should become clear - there's no conversion from built-in functions to the SWIG type for function pointers, so your call to `myfun(test.f)` won't work.

### The solution

The question then is how (and where) do we fix this? In fact there are at least four possible solutions we might pick, depending on how many other languages you target and how "Pythonic" you want to be.

#### Solution 1:

The first solution is trivial. We already used `test.make_fptr()` to return us a Python handle to a function pointer for the funciton `f`. So we can infact call:

```
f=test.make_fptr()
test.myfun(f)
```

Personally I don't like this solution very much, it's not what Python programmers expect and it's not what C programmers expect. The only thing going for it is the simlicity of implementation.

#### Solution 2:

SWIG gives us a mechanism to expose function pointers to the target language, using [`%constant`](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn30). (Normally this is used for exposing compile-time constants, but that's esentially all function pointers really are in their simplest form anyway).

So we can modify our SWIG interface file:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%constant double f(double);
%ignore f;

%include "test.h"
```

The `%constant` directive tells SWIG to wrap `f` as a function pointer, not a function. The `%ignore` is needed to avoid a warning about seeing multiple versions of the same identifier.

(Note: I also removed the `typedef` and `make_fptr()` function from the header file at this point)

Which now lets us run:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> type(test.f)
<type 'SwigPyObject'>
>>> repr(test.f)
"<Swig Object of type 'double (*)(double)' at 0xf7397650>"
```

Great - it's got the function pointer. But there's a snag with this:

```
>>> test.f(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object is not callable
```

Now we can't call `test.f` from the Python side. Which leads to the next solution:

#### Solution 3:

To fix this let's first expose `test.f` as *both* a function pointer and a built-in function. We can do that by simply using `%rename` instead of `%ignore`:

%module test

```
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%constant double f(double);
%rename(f_call) f;

%include "test.h"
```

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> repr(test.f)
"<Swig Object of type 'double (*)(double)' at 0xf73de650>"
>>> repr(test.f_call)
'<built-in function f_call>'
```

That's a step, but I still don't like the idea of having to remember if I should write `test.f_call` or just `test.f` depending on the context of what I want to do with `f` at the time. We can achieve this just by writing some Python code in our SWIG interface:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%rename(_f_ptr) f;
%constant double f(double);
%rename(_f_call) f;

%feature("pythonprepend") myfun %{
  args = f.modify(args)
%}

%include "test.h"

%pythoncode %{
class f_wrapper(object):
  def __init__(self, fcall, fptr):
    self.fptr = fptr
    self.fcall = fcall
  def __call__(self,*args):
    return self.fcall(*args)
  def modify(self, t):
    return tuple([x.fptr if isinstance(x,self.__class__) else x for x in t])

f = f_wrapper(_f_call, _f_ptr)
%}
```

There are several functional bits here. Firstly we create a new, pure Python class to wrap a function as both a callable and a function pointer. It holds as members the real SWIG wrapped (and renamed) function pointer and function. These are now renamed to begin with an underscore as Python convention. Secondly we set `test.f` to be an instance of this wrapper. When it is called as a function it passes the call through. Finally we insert some extra code into the `myfun` wrapper to swap in the real function pointer rather than our wrapper, taking care not to alter any other arguments if there were any.

This does work as expected, for example with:

```
import test
print "As a callable"
test.f(2.0)
print "As a function pointer"
test.myfun(test.f)
```

We could make this a bit nicer, for example with a SWIG macro to avoid repeating the `%rename`, `%constant` and wrapper instance creation, but we can't really escape from the need to use `%feature("pythonprepend")` everywhere we pass these wrappers back to SWIG. (If it is possible to do that transparently it's well beyond my Python knowledge).

#### Solution 4:

The previous solution is somewhat neater, it works transparently as you'd expect (as both a C and Python user) and the mechanics of it is encapsulated with nothing but Python implementing it.

There is a gotcha still though, besides the need to use pythonprepend for every single usage of the function pointers - if you run `swig -python -builtin` it simply won't work, because there's no Python code to prepend in the first place! (You'd need to change the construction of the wrapper to be: `f = f_wrapper(_test._f_call, _test._f_ptr)`, but that won't be sufficient).

So we can work around that by writing some Python C API in our SWIG interface:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%{
static __thread PyObject *callback;
static double dispatcher(double d) {
  PyObject *result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(callback, PyFloat_FromDouble(d), NULL);
  const double ret = PyFloat_AsDouble(result);
  Py_DECREF(result);

  return ret;
}
%}

%typemap(in) double(*)(double) {
  if (!PyCallable_Check($input)) SWIG_fail;
  $1 = dispatcher;
  callback = $input;
}

%include "test.h"
```

This is a little ugly for two reasons. Firstly it uses a (thread local) global variable to store the Python callable. That's trivially fixable for most real world callbacks, where there's a `void*` user data argument as well as the actual inputs to the callback. The "userdata" can be the Python callable in those cases.

The second issue is a little more tricky to solve though - because the callable is a wrapped C function the call sequence now involves wrapping everything up as Python types and a trip up and back from the Python interpreter just to do something that should be trivial. That's quite a bit of overhead.

We can work backwards from a given `PyObject` and try to figure out which function (if any) it is a wrapper for:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%{
static __thread PyObject *callback;
static double dispatcher(double d) {
  PyObject *result = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(callback, PyFloat_FromDouble(d), NULL);
  const double ret = PyFloat_AsDouble(result);
  Py_DECREF(result);

  return ret;
}

SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_f(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);

double (*lookup_method(PyObject *m))(double) {
  if (!PyCFunction_Check(m)) return NULL;
  PyCFunctionObject *mo = (PyCFunctionObject*)m;
  if (mo->m_ml->ml_meth == _wrap_f)
    return f;
  return NULL;
}
%}

%typemap(in) double(*)(double) {
  if (!PyCallable_Check($input)) SWIG_fail;
  $1 = lookup_method($input);
  if (!$1) {
    $1 = dispatcher;
    callback = $input;
  }
}

%include "test.h"
```

This does need some per function pointer code, but now it's an optimisation rather than a requirement and it could be made more generic right a SWIG macro or two.

#### Solution 5:

I was working on a neater 5th solution that would use `%typemap(constcode)` to allow a `%constant` to be used as both a method and a function pointer. It turns out though that there's already support in SWIG for doing exatly that, which I found when reading some of the SWIG source. So actually all we need to do is simply:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%pythoncallback;
double f(double);
%nopythoncallback;

%ignore f;
%include "test.h"
```

The `%pythoncallback` enables some global state that causes subsequent functions to be wrapped as to be usable a both a function pointer and a function! `%nopythoncallback` disables that.

Which then works (with or without `-builtin`) with:

```
import test
test.f(2.0)
test.myfun(test.f)
```

Which solves almost all the problems in one go. This is even [documented](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn30) in the manual too, although there doesn't seem to be any mention of `%pythoncallback`. So the previous four solutions are mostly just useful as examples of customising SWIG interfaces.

There is still one case where solution 4 would be useful though - if you want to mix and match C and Python implemented callbacks you would need to implement a hybrid of these two. (Ideally you'd try and do the SWIG function pointer type conversion in your typemap and then iff that failed fallback to the PyCallable method instead).

Comment: Wow, this is great Flexo. It will take me a little bit of time to absorb all of this but thanks!

Comment: @user1589038 slight facepalm moment: I was going to patch SWIG to add a neater 5th solution, turns out it already exists!

Comment: Can we use a Python function as the callback, i.e. pass `f = lambda x: return x*5` to `test.myfun()` ?

Comment: @kawing-chiu I've got an example of that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11522655/168175 you could combine that with ffi in the same way I showed for Java here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40273233/168175

Comment: @Flexo Thanks! Will have a look.

Comment: Perhaps this is stupid question, but how to get the the return value of callback when myfun is running ? I'm currently performed the python wrapper for C++ function in same way as in solution 5. My function running from python , but I don't know how to read the return value of callback that I passing as a parameter . Can somebody explain how to do this?

Comment: @SomeGenericNameto_Display C it's the last argument to the printf in my example

Comment: @Flexo, Is there some another way to get result of callback except printf from myfun ? E.g. some way on python side ?

Comment: I mean without printf inside myfun .

Comment: Or, perhaps, create an f function on python side which can be passed as an parameter to test.myfun(pyfunction)? Is this is possible ?

Comment: I don't quite follow - why wouldn't you just call test.f  in the python then?

Comment: @Flexo, I'm trying with this sample get the progress of performing myfun thru test.f function. It works for me, I can call f from myfun and pass to the f the current progress and that's great. But I want some way to tracking the progress of myfun on python side.

Comment: I'm also tried to create sample with directors that stored on swig github https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Examples/python/callback 
but it don't work for me, when wrapper created and I try to create the object of class Callback I'm getting the error that such name is not defined . If I'm trying to create new_Callback the object is creating but I can't call any methods cause I have an error that object don't have such attribute. That's why I'm trying to elaborate more with sample where can be defined global functions only ,