# Call C/C++ from Python with hooks to call Python inside C++

Tags: python, swig, python-c-extension

We know we can use SWIG to call C/C++ from Python.

But is that possible to pass on several Python callbacks inside those C/C++?

Basically what I want is: Call C++ from Python:
    pysomeswig.SomeClass(someargs, some_callback)

where some_callback is a Python routine, and SomeClass can call some_callback one or multiple times in its execution.

Is there a way to achieve this kind of things? Thanks..

Comment: Did you read the fine manual?  https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445045/passing-python-functions-to-swig-wrapped-c-code A reference is given to a fully working example