# Interoperability between ctypes and swig for python

Tags: python, c, swig, ctypes

I have a C file that is wrapped with swig. This C file contains an API with function pointer as an argument(shown below).

example.c

```
int binary_op (int a, int b, int (*op)(int,int))
{
    return (*op)(a,b);
}
```

I can map a function to the pointer argument provided that mapping function is defined in same file using swig. But the mapping function is defined in another C file which is wrapped with Ctypes.

testing.c

```
int add_int(int a, int b){
     return a+b;
}
```

In Python, I imported swig generated module and called the API with ctypes generated mapping function, it resulted error.

In testfile.py

```
import example # Module generated by swig

from ctypes import *
wrap_dll = CDLL('testing.dll') # testing.dll is generated with File_2.c

# Mapping function 'add_int' to argument in 'binary_op'
example.binary_op(3,4,wrap_dll.add_int)
```

The error shown is the type of argument is not matching.

```
TypeError: in method 'binary_op', argument 3  of type 'int (*)(int,int)'
```

Comment: We have an error, no code and no question. One out of three for an [mcve], please try to do better.

Comment: Search in here for callback, SWIG and Python and you will find something that you can use. It is there

Comment: @JensMunk: I have searched quiet a lot but nothing seems related. Any help would be appreciated in case if you able to guide me to related stuff. Thanks

Comment: @Anthon Try take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445045/passing-python-functions-to-swig-wrapped-c-code

Comment: @JensMunk: Thanks for the link. I have managed to do the mapping between ctypes and swig wrapped functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a ctypes function like below in python:

```
py_callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p, c_int, c_int)
```

where the return type and arguments type resembles the function pointer argument. Now I wrapped the mapping function 'add' to the above ctypes function.

```
f = py_callback_type(add)
```

And finally I casted the wrapped function with return type as pointer and the '.value' gives the address of the wrapped pointer function.

```
f_ptr = cast(f, c_void_p).value
```

Then in the swig interface file, using typemaps, I have changed the pointer argument as below:

`extern int binary_op (int a, int b, int INPUT);`

Now when I map the function to the pointer, the address of the mapping function will be passed as an integer INPUT to the binary_op function.
Since the argument is a pointer, the function in the address will be mapped.

```
example.binary_op(4,5,f_ptr) ==> 9 //mapped function is 'add(int a, int b)' --> returns a+b
```