# Calling undefined number of callback functions from the C++ layer

Tags: python, c++, callback, swig

Recently I started to use SWIG to develop a solution that passes (possibly) several callback functions that should be called in the C++ layer. Besides, I spent some time reading the [introduction callback chapter](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn30) and the [director feature](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_target_language_callbacks).

I've managed to achieve my goal by coding different classes that inherit from the base class in the C++ layer from the [documentation example](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.1/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_target_language_callbacks), but I'm trying to learn in how to pass `std::function` instances instead of pointer to classes.

I believe that the (incorrect) example below summarizes my objective:

File example.h:

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Controller {
 private:
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions;

 public:
  virtual void AddFunction(const std::function<void(void)>& func) {
    functions.push_back(func);
  }

  virtual void Execute() {
    for (int m = 0; m < functions.size(); ++m) functions[m]();
  }

  Controller() {}
  virtual ~Controller() {}
};
```

File example.i:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "example.h"
```

File example.py:

```
import example

def foo():
    print("yey")

def bar():
    print("dog")

def cat():
   print("miaw")

e = example.Controller()
e.AddFunction(foo)
e.AddFunction(bar)
e.AddFunction(cat)

# Prints yey, dog and miaw sequentially
e.Execute()
```

So, my question is:

1. Am I in the right direction here? In other words, is this really possible to do with SWIG?
2. Can I achieve my goal with the director feature only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use directors a class with a virtual function to override is needed.

Given your `Controller` definition as `test.h`:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Controller {
 private:
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions;

 public:
  virtual void AddFunction(const std::function<void(void)>& func) {
    functions.push_back(func);
  }

  virtual void Execute() {
    for (int m = 0; m < functions.size(); ++m) functions[m]();
  }

  Controller() {}
  virtual ~Controller() {}
};
```

Then the SWIG interface file (`test.i`) could declare a director-enabled `Callback` class and extend `Controller` to take that class as a parameter and call the overridden virtual function:

```cpp
%module(directors="1") test

%feature("director") Callback;

%inline %{
class Callback {
public:
    virtual void function() = 0;
    virtual ~Callback() {}
};
%}

%{
#include "test.h"
%}
%include "test.h"

%extend Controller {
    void AddFunction(Callback* cb) {
        $self->AddFunction(std::bind(&Callback::function, cb));
    }
}
```

The Python code would look like:

```py
import test

class Foo(test.Callback):
    def function(self):
        print('yey')

class Bar(test.Callback):
    def function(self):
        print('dog')

class Cat(test.Callback):
    def function(self):
        print('miaw')

# Note that AddFunction needs to be provided an object instance that persists
# until after Execute is called, so "e.AddFunction(Foo())" wouldn't work
# because Foo() would be freed after the AddFunction call.
foo = Foo()
bar = Bar()
cat = Cat()

e = test.Controller()
e.AddFunction(foo)
e.AddFunction(bar)
e.AddFunction(cat)
e.Execute()
```

Output:

```
yey
dog
miaw
```

This is the `.i` file to use to directly add functions and not use directors.  This works with the `example.py` in the question and is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522655/235698):

```cpp
%module example

%inline %{
class PyCallback
{
    PyObject *func;
    PyCallback& operator=(const PyCallback&); // Not allowed
public:
    PyCallback(const PyCallback& o) : func(o.func) {
        Py_XINCREF(func);
    }
    PyCallback(PyObject *func) : func(func) {
        Py_XINCREF(this->func);
        assert(PyCallable_Check(this->func));
    }
    ~PyCallback() {
        Py_XDECREF(func);
    }
    void operator()(void) {
      if (!func || Py_None == func || !PyCallable_Check(func))
          return;
      PyObject *result = PyObject_CallNoArgs(func);
      Py_XDECREF(result);
    }
};
%}

%{
#include "test.h"
%}
%include "test.h"

%extend Controller {
    void AddFunction(PyObject* cb) {
        $self->AddFunction(PyCallback(cb));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. Though I'm strongly accepting your suggestion, I'm trying to get rid of declaring a new class for each callback. For instance, in Python, we should always have a `class Something(test.Callback)`. In C#, something like `public class Something : Callback`. Not to mention if I decide to consider the rule of one class definition per file... Therefore, is there any solution where the C++ layer requires a method instead of a class?

Comment: There is, but it is more complicated without directors.  Your C callback needs a `void* context`-like parameter because some context has to be tracked converting a Python callback into a C one.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522655/235698) for a C++ example.  C needs the context parameter to hold the state that the C++ object maintains, so you don't need the context parameter using C++.  I was thinking of a C project I did where context was needed.

Comment: The link to the other answer seems to be exactly what I was looking for. It seems to me that, while the director feature is a language-agnostic approach, the "`context`" approach is tailored to the target language. Thank you :)

Comment: @JoséJoaquim Added an updated `test.i` that works with your example.py based on the answer I linked.